# How to use this.props in React Styled Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I am trying to style my component using `props` likes this:

```
const MyStyledComponent = styled.div`
    position: fixed;
    top: ${this.props.style.top};
    left: ${this.props.style.left};
    width: ${this.props.style.width};
    height: ${this.props.style.height};
`;
```

But I am getting the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined

Comment: You should use destructuring to get nested object values, you can use fallback values in case props aren't available.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to use a callback which accepts `props` passed to the component like so:

```
const MyStyledComponent = styled.div`
  position: fixed;
  top: ${(props) => props.top};
`;

<MyStyledComponent top={5} />;
```

See [Getting Started in docs](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#getting-started).

---

**Bonus:** typically when working with css-in-js 
(like `styled-component`), there are [many handy tools](https://styled-components.com/ecosystem) that used alongside, like [`styled-tools`](https://github.com/diegohaz/styled-tools).

```
import styled, { createGlobalStyle } from "styled-components";
import { prop } from "styled-tools";

const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle`
  body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 5px solid pink;
  }
`;

const Box = styled.div`
  height: ${({ height }) => height}px;
  width: ${({ width }) => width}px;
  background-color: ${({ color }) => color};
`;

const Box2 = styled.div`
  ${({ height, width, color }) => ({
    height,
    width,
    "background-color": color
  })}
`;

const Box3 = styled.div`
  height: ${prop("height")}px;
  width: ${prop("width")}px;
  background-color: ${prop("color")};
`;

const N = 100;

const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <GlobalStyle />
      <Box width={N} height={N} color="palevioletred" />
      <Box2 width={N * 1.5} height={N * 1.5} color="black" />
      <Box3 width={N * 2} height={N * 2} color="palegoldenrod" />
    </>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit affectionate-moon-netoi]

[image]

Comment: Dennis, I'm new into react, but in this case where the code uses `props` more than once, was not it better to have a function component which takes `props` instead to write an arrow function all the time?

Comment: I'll elaborate with more examples